# Why are the hidden links throughout my page still appearing in the noscript tags?

Tags: html, noscript

I have been working on a simple web site (one page at the moment) to display some basic information. This site also contains several links that refer the user to downloadable content (2 links to a PDF and one link to a zip file).

These links, like most of my page, are hidden using the `display:none` CSS attribute if the user cannot run JavaScript, which several features of the site require. A message is then displayed in the `<noscript>` tag to inform the user of why they aren't seeing the scripted content. This was all working perfectly when I previewed the files on my personal computer without hosting them.

My problem came after hosting on the site on GoDaddy.com. Now, whenever `<noscript>` is called upon (regardless of browser), every link from my site is pulled out and shoved in the upper-left corner where the user can see it. CSS styling does not appear to affect these links and I cannot figure out how to get rid of them.

How can I solve this? Most importantly, how to make the links go away unless I set them to visible again?

This is my `<noscript>` tag, at the bottom of the page:

```
<noscript>
    <div class="scriptError">
        <h1>Javascript is disabled!</h1>
        <div id="noScriptNotice">
            <p>This site works best with Javascript enabled. A 'noscript-friendly' version is currently in progress, but for now please enable Javascript to view the contents.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Everything else (including links) is inside this div:

```
<div class="scriptedContent" style="display: none;">
<script>
    //If scripting is enabled, display the site.
    $(".scriptedContent").css("display", "block");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's working on your own localhost, but not Godaddy.com , you should first and foremost try to submit a support ticket to see if that provides any help.

The links that are re-appearing, see if you can apply this CSS style to the links that you are trying to hide:

```
font-size: 0;
text-decoration: none;
```

That should do the trick of hiding the links, that is, if your CSS is affecting them at all.
If not, try to "right click > view source" of the page, and then view and compare the source with your own.

**Alternative if that does not work:**
Try making your links (in the HTML code) something along the lines of:

```
<a href="#" style="display:none;"> Text </a>
```

and seeing if that stops them from overriding your Styling.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I inspected the elements as you suggested and it seems that inline styling of display: block and visibility: visible are somehow being added by the hosting site (I set link styling to display:none all over the place to test that, and sure enough my CSS script is overwritten when the hosting site kicks in). I have contacted support and am waiting to hear back now.

Comment: @FSHutch great to hear that! Hope everything sorts out alright! Though, now I have a slight question myself, are the people at GoDaddy.com somehow automatically linking their own CSS sheet to your website that you can see in the source for that page? Have you double checked the uploaded version, and tried removing it if it shows up? I have also added an alternative, it might be worth it to try and use that.

Comment: They had a default CSS file that I deleted, but currently the page source isn't showing any excess CSS files that shouldn't be there. I have double checked the uploaded version several times, but the problem persists no matter what I change. I would upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation. :)

Comment: haha thanks, let me keep thinking for a bit.
Mind sending me the link to your website? I might be able to help.

Comment: Fixed! The issue turned out to be similar to one caused by Firefox's NoScript plugin; basically, if you have all of your links hidden, it assumes you would have unhidden them with scripting and so it "helps" you by setting them to visible automatically. Fixed it by placing a link that was not hidden (set opacity to 0 for now) outside of the hidden content in the noscript tag. Messy, but it's a start and solves the issue. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: No problem! Another solution is maybe placing an empty link, like: <a href="#"></a>, it might count that as visible and not do anything, if you want to avoid positioning errors :) Glad I could help